# Eclipse PDT extension points and usage

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to get started developing eclipse plugins, specifically extending [PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/). Is there a list of extensions points, docs, other how to's?

The latest versions, as of writing, are Eclipse Juno 4.2 + PDT 3.1.0.

I've checked [eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org), there's nothing on PDT. The best I found in the wiki is [a few notes on pdt 2.0](http://wiki.eclipse.org/API_Document_for_Extension_Points_PDT_2.0).

### Update - Bounty

What I am looking for:

- List of PDT extension points
- Links to any documentation (api's, manual, etc)

For each extension point:

- Available since what version?
- A summary of what each extension point is for would be great.

Extra credit:

- Any links to articles, tutorials, etc. or example usage for any of the points would be fantastic.

Comment: You might want to accept some answers first..

Comment: I'm searching for this kind of material as well. Anyway I found this list, which could be helpfull for many others: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Foverview-summary.html Even if it's not for the latest version (it is for release 3.7) it may be helpfull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be up-to-date, comprehensive documentation for PDT development around. The only pieces I could find are [Extending PDT 2.2](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Extending_PDT_2.2) and the [PDT 0.7 Design Document](http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/5/54/API_PDT.pdf).

There is, however, a way to build the list of PDT extension points, including since which version they are available and some documentation:

1. Setup Eclipse according to [Working with PDT source code in Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/Contributing#Working_with_PDT_source_code_in_Eclipse). Note that you should do point 5., "Install missing dependencies", before point 2., "Check out PDT plugins to Eclipse workspace". Also note that beside the missing dependencies mentioned, you will need "EGit Project Set Support" (and possibly more dependencies) to be able to import the Team Project Set from Git.
2. Once the Project Set is imported, switch to the "Plug-in Development" Perspective and open the "Plug-ins" View. Locate the PDT-Plugins.

   [image]
3. Double clicking each plugin will open its Plugin editor, with general Information about the plugin and - a list of extensions and extension points of this plugin. Opening the "Extension Points" link or tab will - if there are extension points - give you another link: "Show extension point description", including "Since" and "Description". There you are!

Some background about Eclipse Extension Points and Extensions: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseExtensionPoint/article.html#extensionpoints

Comment: I got stuck on step #1 *Working with PDT source code in Eclipse* step #2 *"Check out PDT plugins to Eclipse workspace"*. However, `git clone git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/pdt/org.eclipse.pdt.git` > File > Import... > Existing Projects into Workspace > Next > Select root directory :: Browse (navigate to the root directory where you cloned pdt) > Finish... Now your step #3 work.

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree with the previous answer. There just is no up-to-date extension point documentation for PDT. Even worse, there are still extension points in the repository which are not being used anymore by PDT. I have collected a couple of links to dltk/pdt development tutorials in the [wiki](https://github.com/pulse00/Symfony-2-Eclipse-Plugin/wiki/Development-links) of one of my plugins. To setup your development environment quickly, you can use [this](https://github.com/pulse00/Symfony-2-Eclipse-Plugin/wiki/Development-environment) tutorial.

I would advise you to go through the sourcecode of existing PDT extensions and learn from the existing code. You can find a list of existing pdt extensions in [this wiki.](https://github.com/PHPsrc/wiki/wiki/PDT-Extension-project-list)

And of course you can always ask on the [PDT mailing list](https://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/pdt-dev) for help.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, in the Eclipse Luna reference: http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Findex.html&cp=46_1_1